# Autostart an application in android 10

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to launch an application once my android is finished booting. @user:3801327 has stated You could do this in several ways:

Have your app act as launcher ( set launcher declarations in manifest and set it as default launcher)
Modify your default launcher (e.g. Launcher3) to start the app when the launcher starts.
Modify SystemUI app to start your app when it first starts.
Modify SystemServer or one of the system services ( e.g. ActivityManagerService ) to start your app when the correct boot phase is reached (e.g. PHASE_BOOT_COMPLETED )

I would like to modify the launcher to make this happen by decompiling it and adding the autostart command to the launcher but I am unsure how to do that. Alternatively, I am fine doing it in init.rc but for some reason it isn't running my script (test.sh). If someone can explain either of these options I would be grateful.

Comment: I'm not shure is that question is asked by very beginner or very advanced user... why won't you make your app a launcher? or just handle `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission and broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running it with activity manager in the init script somewhere on early boot Im guessing?
Use the following command

```
am start -n com.you.package/.your.activity -a android.intent.action.VIEW

for example
am start -n com.example.app/.ui.activities.login.LoginActivity -a android.intent.action.VIEW
```

Im not sure if init script supports this so you could just make a bash script which runs this command and call that bash script in your init script

Answer (score 0):

Given I was working on Android 10 and it has different security then what I am used to the easiest solution for me was to modify the launcher to boot the application when it the launcher launches.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).